# When might we expect a 32 GB image for the Nexus 7?

Tags: lubuntu, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I was very impressed with the functionality of Raring with LXDE on the Nexus 7 --- I was able to run the same applications as on my laptop but with significantly better battery life.

I did some experimenting with Unity on an ongoing basis, but spent most of my time using LXDE  (where I managed to achieve stable operation). The only major problem was space - although the Nexus 7 I have is a 32 GB version, the only installation image I could find was for an 8 GB install, leaving only a few hundred MB for development.

This storage capacity is not quite enough for me to work with and as a result, the Nexus 7 is gathering dust until I can find a larger image. If a 32 GB image were available again then there might end up being a large number of users out there and I would be one of them.

When might we expect a 32 GB image of Ubuntu for the Nexus 7?

Thanks for the great work! - Chris

Comment: You have a "32 GB" Nexus, and the install is "8 GB" but that only leaves you with a few MB?? And in theory, you would develop in your casual PC/Laptop and just load the app to the phone/tablet when you want to test it. (It is difficult/uncomfortable to type code in phone/tablet.)

Comment: What would be nice is for the **grouper** image to auto-detect, and re-size (at install), for 8GB, 16GB and 32GB models. *However, that may not be a priority for developers (with current focus on MIR, etc.).*